# NLog not writing to eventlog .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, nlog, asp.net-core-2.1

I've added NLog to my .NET core console app and it works with file and database targets. However when i try and get it to work with eventviewer it doesn't log anything. When i add the code for the eventviewer target the file and database part doesn't log anything. When I remove it, the logging starts working again.

I have added a new event viewer source for the application using Powershell, so that wouldn't be the issue. The application doesn't crash or report an error, it runs fine but doesn't log anything when event viewer is included.

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  internalLogFile="c:\temp\console-example-internal.log"
  internalLogLevel="Info" >

<targets>    
  <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="c:\temp\console-example.log"
        layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-e
        vent-properties}" />

<target xsi:type="Console" name="console"
        layout="[${longdate}][${machinename}][${level:uppercase=true}] ${message} ${exception}" />

<target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" source="testlogging" log="Application"
        layout="${message}${newline}${exception:format=ToString}" />

  <target xsi:type="Database" name="database" >
      <connectionString>Server=test; Database=test; User Id=sa; Password=password;</connectionString>
      <commandText>
          INSERT INTO dbo.Log (Application, Logged, Level, Message, Logger, CallSite, Exception ) 
          VALUES (@Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message, @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@application" layout="TestLoggingApp" />
      <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="url: ${aspnet-request-url} | action: ${aspnet-mvc-action} | ${message}" />

      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
  </target>    
</targets>

<rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile, console, database" />        
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Any ideas on how to implement this or if I have missed something?

Comment: What does the internal logging tell you?  I usually find it to be extremely detailed.

Comment: Yes i forgot about the internal logging. Thanks. I added the nuget package Rolf mentioned below and i got the following error when trying:

2018-07-31 17:15:43.8327 Info Loading assembly: NLog.WindowsEventLog
2018-07-31 17:15:44.0588 Error Error parsing layout all-e             vent-properties will be ignored. Exception: System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'all-e             vent-properties'
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String name)
   at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.GetLayoutRenderer(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, String name)

Comment: @user2661305 Can see that you have add a newline in your `logfile` target. Try to write `${all-event-properties}` without using newlines

Answer (score 7):

For me the answer was adding "NLog.WindowsEventLog" assembly to the extensions area to nlog.config:

```
<extensions>
   <add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog" />
</extensions>
```

I had the default:  "NLog.Web.AspNetCore".

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out. Didn't find this in NLog-documentation.  
So the needs are:  
1. Use NLog and NLog.WindowsEventLog packages  
2. Be aware thad eventlog-source is created. commandline:  
`eventcreate /ID 1 /L APPLICATION /T INFORMATION /SO MyEventSource /D "EventSource created"`  
3. in NLog.config: configure target, rule, AND the extension @Jim Neff mentioned.

Comment: Still needed this to make latest NLog work in .NET 6 app

Answer (score 1):

.Net Core is a subset of the .Net Framework, and doesn't include things like Windows EventLog (as this doesn't exist on other non-Windows-devices).

You should make sure to check the platform support documentation first:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/platform-support

There you will see that a special Nuget-package has been created for .Net Core-applications on the Windows platform:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.WindowsEventLog/

Comment: Thanks for that. I added this package there now and ran this app again and i can now see what the error is:

2018-07-31 17:15:43.8327 Info Loading assembly: NLog.WindowsEventLog

2018-07-31 17:15:44.0588 Error Error parsing layout all-event-properties will be ignored. Exception: System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'all-event-properties' at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String name) at NLog.Layouts.LayoutParser.GetLayoutRenderer(ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, String name)

Comment: @user2661305 Can see that you have add a newline in your `logfile` target. Try to write `${all-event-properties}` without using newlines

Comment: I've excluded the newline and left only the message & exception. Still an error: 2018-08-01 Error parsing layout all-event-properties will be ignored. Exception: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'all-event-properties' at NLog.Config.Factory...
2018-08-01 Error Parsing configuration from C:\Users\user20\source\repos\TestLogging\TestLogging\nlog.config failed. Exception: Exception when parsing C:\Users\user20\source\repos\TestLogging\TestLogging\nlog.config. ---> Target cannot be found: 'EventLog' at NLog.Config.Factory

Comment: @user2661305 Try remove everything from your NLog.config except the `EventLog`-target and a single logging-rule. Instead trying to fly on first attempt. Then work from there like all developers do.

Comment: Hi, I've striped everything out leaving just the eventlog rule and targets. It still falls over with the error: Error Parsing configuration - Target cannot be found: 'EventLog'... Should this work seamlessly when I add the nuget package or is there anything extra that needs done to use the NLog.WindowsEventLog package? I've added this line into my config thinking that i might need it too: <extensions>
   <add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog" />
</extensions>

Comment: @user2661305 There is a bug in ver. 4.5.7 of the nuget-package. Until the bug is fixed, then you can use https://nuget.org/packages/NLog.WindowsEventLog/4.5.6