# Adding EventLog as target in NLog for .NET Core app causes Parsing configuration error

Tags: .net-core, nlog, event-log

I have a .NET Core Console app where I use NLog.
When I try to add EventLog as target in the nlog.config the load of the configuration failes with the following:

> System.ArgumentException: Target cannot be found: 'EventLog'.

I have found a similar question in stackoverflow: 
[NLog not writing to eventlog .NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615831/nlog-not-writing-to-eventlog-net-core-2-1). And the suggested solution is to add the Nuget-package NLog.WindowsEventLog which I have. And the version I have downloaded is 4.5.10 so it should not have the bug in v. 4.5.7 mentioned in the other stackoverflow post. And it still does not work.

Here is some information:

- BCL: .NETCore.App (2.1.2)
- Dependencies from NLog:

  - NLog (4.5.10)
  - NLog.Extensions.Logging (1.3.0)
  - NLog.WindowsEventLog (4.5.10)

And here is the nlog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XSD manual extracted from package NLog.Schema: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="logs\internal-log.log"
      internalLogLevel="Trace" >

     <!-- the targets to write to -->
      <targets>
          <target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" source="testlogging" 
log="Application" layout="${message}" />
      </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="eventlog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Thanks @Julian. Now it works. A bit confusing that it is not enough to add the NLog.WIndowsEventLog as a dependency in the project file but that you also has to define the dependency in the nlog.config file. But I am very happy that it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to your config, after the `<nlog ...>`

```xml
<extensions>
   <add assembly="NLog.WindowsEventLog"/>
</extensions>
```

if that won't work, check the internal log: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging